# Upload and use web folder on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We already allow our users to upload files through the app to the Azure Blob Storage, and then view them inside the app.

What we need now is to allow the upload of an entire folder containing web files (html, js, css, images...) maintaining the folder structure that it has and then be able to *run* these files in the browser. The link references between the files must be maintained also so it can work.

What will be the correct way to do this?
Is it possible through Blob Storage or do we need to upload the folder and its contents directly to the file system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the Azure Blob storage doesn't have a concept of a "folder".  The closest you would get would be to name a file "foldername/filename.ext".  How you populate blob storage in this fashion would depend on how you allow a user to upload all their files.  Perhaps as a zip file or through some form of ajax-based file upload UI on a web page... not sure.  Ultimately you can't build folders but should be able to replicate the behaviours of one.